# 2 folders in Sys/Class/Backlight?

Tags: 11.10, graphics, intel-graphics, brightness

**ISSUE:** Backlight brightness does not change.

**More Detail:** Brightness will not change, using both 'System Settings->Screen', or <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys (Brightness bar shows and moves, but screen brightness does not change).

Noticed [a post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866283) about having multiple folders in Sys->Class->Backlight. I HAVE TWO FOLDERS TOO: `intel_backlight` and `acpi_video0`.

Using the function keys, alters the value in the `acpi_video0`'s 'Brightness' file - But doesn't actually alter the brightness of the screen.

If I add `backlight=vendor` in Grub, my function keys then edit the value in the `Intel_Backlight` brightness file. - But again doesn't actually change the brightness of the screen.

**Computer:** Fujitsu Siemans Pi2515, Intel Integrated Graphics, No HDD partition.

**Already Tried:**

- Editing grub to contain: `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor`
- http://ubuntuguide.net/change-screen-brightness-with-fn-key-in-ubuntu-11-0410-10

  ```
  sudo apt-get install acpi
  sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=20
  ```
- Brightness does not adjust in fallback mode either.
- Reinstalling OS, Using Linux Mint (Same problem).
- Upgrading and downgrading BIOS.

Many thanks for reading, I understand this problem may need a bit of a Linux pro to sort. If anyone up for the challenge I'll spend any amount of time being walked through this, posting results. Don't want to give up here!

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar problem with a Toshiba Portege R935 in 12.04. I can't change the brightness after suspending and resuming.

The Grub line didn't help either (actually with that line, it stopped working even before suspending).

In the meantime, I discovered this workaround:

- as root, change the value in `sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`. for instance:

  ```
  echo 2937 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
  ```

**Warning**: these values are not between `0` and `7` (as the ones in the other directory), but between `284` and `4539`, or something like that.

Comment: One-liner that doesn't require `su root`? Yep, here you go: `echo 2937 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Answer (score -2):

If you tried everything else and your system's backlight non-responsive and if you are using an Intel 915 or descendent thereof ("945GSE", etc.) then your issue may be [backlight inversion confusion on gen4](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/rNRcWIBtZvqyeCL2pS0E).

Comment: -1 The link went offline. It's essential content should have been cited here in the first place.