# Ubuntu 12.04 - Unable to change brightness [ATI HD xxxx - Toshiba Satellite L510 19e]

Tags: ati, brightness, toshiba-satellite

i can't change my brighness. On my Ubuntu is the original Driver from ati.com running.
i used Ubuntu 12.4 with the lastest Updates.

Can everyone help me?
Thanks Guys!

my xorg.conf:

> Section "ServerLayout"
>     Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
>     Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
>   EndSection
>
> Section "Module"
>     Load  "glx"
>   EndSection
>
> Section "Monitor"
>     Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
>     Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
>     Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
>     Option      "DPMS" "true"
>   EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>     Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
>     Driver      "fglrx"
>     BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
>   EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>     Identifier "Default Screen"
>     DefaultDepth     24
>   EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>     Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
>     Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
>     Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
>     DefaultDepth     24
>     SubSection "Display"
>         Viewport   0 0
>         Depth     24
>     EndSubSection
>   EndSection

Comment: Check if this is happening to you: http://askubuntu.com/q/151024/51306

Answer (score -1):

Its working for me :)

Follow the instructions in the link

http://vedimpokem.blogspot.in/2013/02/adjust-screen-brightness-ubuntu-1204.html

Comment: Links are great, but please edit your answer to include the relevant content from that page, since if that page is moved or deleted, this answer becomes useless.